# click(dataMap, method) version of the jQuery is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried to pass data through the click method to test it out so that I do not have to call a function from handler `onclick`. I want to do this to prevent the default submit whenever I press any button. Like this instead of having.

```
<button onclick="addAuthor()">Add Author</button>
```

I can have something like:

```
<button id="addAuthor">Add Author</button>
```

Which would go to.

```
$("#addAuthor").click({
    id: 100
}, addAuthor);
```

Then.

```
function addAuthor(dataMap) {
    alert(dataMap.data.id)
    //add another author
}
```

I want the button "Remove div2" to do the same thing the span "Remove" does.
For now I had it to give an alert with the value of 100 but it does not even do that.

```
$("removeDiv").click({bookDiv: count}, removeDiv);
```

This is what I want to put so that the variables are passed but the test doesn't work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
    <!-- #main {
      max-width: 800px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    -->
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="main">
    <h1>Add or Remove text boxes with jQuery</h1>
    <div class="my-form">
      <!--            <form action="next.php" method="post">-->
      <button onclick="addAuthor()">Add Author</button>
      <br>
      <br>
      <div id="addAuth"></div>
      <br>
      <br>
      <button onclick="submit()">Submit</button>
      <!--            </form>-->
    </div>

    <div id="result"></div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////
     //HERE
    $("#removeDiv1").click({
      id: 100
    }, removeDiv1);
     ////////////////////////////////////////////////
    var authors = 0;

    function addAuthor() {
      authors++;
      var str = '<br/>' + '<div id="auth' + authors + '">' + '<input type="text" name="author" id="author' + authors + '" placeholder="Author Name:"/>' + '<br/>' + '<button onclick="addMore(\'auth' + authors + '\')" >Add Book</button>' + '</div>';
      $("#addAuth").append(str);
    }

    var count = 0;

    function addMore(id) {
      count++;
      var str =
        '<div id="bookDiv' + count + '">' + '<input class="' + id + '" type="text" name="book' + id + '" placeholder="Book Name"/>' + '<span onclick="removeDiv(\'bookDiv' + count + '\')">Remove</span>'
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////
        ////HERE
        + '<button id="removeDiv1">   Remove div2</button>'
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////
        + '</div>';
      $("#" + id).append(str);
    }

    function removeDiv(id) {
        $("#" + id).slideUp(function() {
          $("#" + id).remove();
        });
      }
      ///////////////////////////////////////////
      //HERE

    function removeDiv1(dataMap) {
        alert(dataMap.data.id)
      }
      ///////////////////////////////////////////

    function submit() {
      var arr = [];
      for (i = 1; i <= authors; i++) {
        var obj = {};
        obj.name = $("#author" + i).val();
        obj.books = [];
        $(".auth" + i).each(function() {
          var data = $(this).val();
          obj.books.push(data);
        });
        arr.push(obj);
      }
      sendToServer(arr)
      $("#result").html(JSON.stringify(arr));
    }

    function sendToServer(data) {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {
          arr: JSON.stringify(data)
        },
        url: "next.php",
        success: function() {

        }
      });
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't with passing in the dataMap (try it without it; it still won't work).

The problem is that when you attempt to set your click handler with `$("#removeDiv1").click(...)`, the #removeDiv1 element *doesn't exist yet* - it's created and added to the DOM later, in addMore.

You need to do one of the following:

1. Set your click handler inside of addMore, after str is appended.
2. Change your click handler to use jQuery's event delegation capabilities. `$("#removeDiv1").click(...)` becomes `$("body").on('click', '#removeDiv1', ...)`

Side note: the "body" selector can be replaced by any selector that will select an ancestor of #removeDiv1; the click event propagates up from #removeDiv1 to its parent, its parent parent, and so on, until it's handled and something calls e.stopPropagation(), or until it reaches the document root.

Answer (score 0):

First off, this is really something that Angular or something like it can do much better.

Next, I wouldn't use ids.  You can do the same thing with classes without having to increment and restrict your code.  Here's how I'd code the HTML:

```
<div>
  <h1>My favorite authors and their books</h1>
  <button class="js-add">Add An Author</button>
  <div class="authors"></div>
  <button class="js-save">Save</button>
</div>
```

I've also pulled all the javascript out of the HTML.

Next, "click" won't apply to items added after it is stated.  You either need to re-state a click for the new element, or you need to use "on".  Note in the code below that I can use the "click" method for "add Author" because that button exists when the script was run.  For the other buttons, I had to use "on('click'..."

```
var addAuthor = function($this) {
  var books = $('<div>')
    .addClass('books')
    .append(
      $('<button>')
      .addClass('js-addBook')
      .html('Add a book')
    )
    .append(
      $('<div>')
      .addClass('bookName')
      .html('Books:')
    );
  addBook(books.find('button'));
  $($this)
    .parent()
    .find('.authors')
    .append(
      $('<div>')
      .addClass('author')
      .append(
        $('<div>')
        .addClass('authorName')
        .html('Author: ')
        .append(
          $('<div>')
          .addClass('remove js-removeAuthor')
          .html('x')
        )
        .append(
          $('<input>')
        )
      )
      .append(
        books
      )
    )
};
var addBook = function($this) {
  $($this)
    .parent()
    .append(
      $('<div>')
      .addClass('book')
      .append(
        $('<div>')
        .addClass('remove js-removeBook')
        .html('x')
      )
      .append(
        $('<input>')
      )
    )
};
addAuthor($('button.addAuthor'));
$('.js-addAuthor').click(function() {
  addAuthor(this);
});
$('.authors').on('click', '.js-addBook', function() {
  addBook(this);
});
$('.authors').on('click', '.js-removeBook, .js-removeAuthor', function() {
  $(this)
    .parent()
    .remove()
});
```

Here's a jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/mckinleymedia/rt3tpeta/3/